# Laravel won't return records with 0000-00-00 as date

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm upgrading an old database, 250k+ records, some of them (1k) with (mysql8) illegal 0000-00-00 date values. I'm planning to replace them with NULL, however Laravel, for some reason, is unable to retrieve these records. I did few experiments:

1. `Profile::where('birth_date', '0000-00-00')->get();` -> 0 results
2. `Profile::whereIn('birth_date', ['0000-00-00'])->get();` -> 0 results
3. `Profile::whereRaw('birth_date = 0000-00-00')->get();` -> working fine

For now, I'm using #3 but I'm curious why #1 isn't working, nor #2. Of course custom dates are working fine in all scenarios, same with raw sql query in PMA.

Type of `birth_date` column is `date`. Using MySQL 8, Laravel 8 and PHP 8. Thanks

Comment: Can you just do it in MySQL with a single query manually?

Comment: Laravel uses strict mode by default, you can fixed this by changing `strict => true` to  to `strict => false` from `config/database.php`

Comment: @sta thanks, you're right. I'll keep strict mode enabled and use whereRaw() condition instead.